# Cannot import scipy in ipython (python 3.4.4)

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, ipython

I have a working setup for Jupyter Notebooks (numpy, scipy, matplotlib, etc.) on workstation 1. I went to set up a second workstation (bash shell on windows 10):

1. Installed Python 3.4.4 from www.python.org, windows 64 bit.
2. Upgraded pip: $ python -m pip install --upgrade pip, now its (v 9.0.1)
3. Installed numpy with pip
4. Installed scipy with pip
   $ pip install scipy

> Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\python34\lib\site-packages
>
> Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in
>   c:\python34\lib\site-packages     (from scipy)

See image. When I try to import scipy in ipython I get this '_ccallback_c' error.
[image]

I've searched google and this site for importing scipy and this error, but nothing has shown up. Thanks for your help.

Comment: try `pip3 install scipy`

Comment: Hmm. Beeing on windows, using the official python-distribution and then calling ```pip install scipy``` will never (except you got a crazily complete system; i highly doubt that: BLAS, LAPACK, Fortran-compiler and co.) work! So double-check what happened when installing scipy. Look also here on SO for ```windows install scipy``` questions which will recommend Gohlke's binaries OR the anaconda-distribution (which i recommend). It's also the official recommendation of scipy-devs (on windows)!

Comment: Personally, and being a Windows user exclusively myself, I've learned the best way to install or upgrade packages is from binaries provided by http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ . I think I recall `pip install numpy` didn't install the Numpy+MKL version which is needed. @sascha is right.

Comment: SOLVED: Thanks for your help @sascha and Jarad. I installed all my packages from Gohlke and we're off and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the comments, Windows users like myself need to use packages from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ (or something alike). 
I downloaded the packages I wanted of the correct type (python 3.4, 64 bit windows) and extracted them in my Python>Lib>site-packages folder. Time for data analysis.